# render_template giving internal server error in aws beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jinja2

I am trying to host a simple application in AWS elasticbeanstalk however when I am using render_template it is giving me this error "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

Here is my flask code,

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests

application = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates", static_folder="static")

@application.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# run the app.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.debug = True
    application.run()
```

My HTML code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <h1>Hello, Flask!</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My Dir Structure,

```
templates
  |
   ------> index.html
application.py
requirments.txt
```

But When I dont use render_template i dont see any issue, Here is the code,

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests

application = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates", static_folder="static")

@application.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello Flask!!"

# run the app.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.debug = True
    application.run()
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit -

I was able to fix this issue, The problem was with the zip folder which I had created. Once I created a proper zip and uploaded it to aws beanstalk it started working.